# Outlets (top only) and lights wired together with trail wire not working

Tags: receptacle, 120-240v

I have a room in my house where the top of each outlet is controlled by a switch, and all of the ceiling lights by another switch.  I thought I could just bypass the switch for the outlets and have them on at all times, but it turned out to be more complicated than I anticipated.  I would like some help putting it back to the way it was.  Trouble is, I do not remember the way it was.  There are only two wires coming into the switches indicated below, one coming into the room from the ceiling (top) and one coming into the room through the floor (bottom).

Here is how it is now:

[image]

Problem is, now nothing works.  What is the correct way to wire this?

EDIT:  I do know for sure there was a trail wire connecting the two switches, I just do not know how they were connected

EDIT: Here is how the outlets are wired

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where in your diagram are the outlets connected?

Comment: Unless I tear up all the walls I am not sure.  Is there any easy way to figure that out without tearing into walls?

Comment: Do (or did) any of those white wires have any markings or tape on them?

Comment: The way you have your diagram drawn you need to have *both* switches on in order to complete your circuit. Which direction is your power coming from?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Let me climb into my attic quick and figure out where the top wire goes.  Should be able to figure this out by process of elimination

Comment: @ShemSeger I just got a non contact voltage tester, it looks like power is coming in through the bottom feed

Comment: @brhans I just looked in my attic and from what I can see the top wire in the diagram goes to the lights, they are all daisy chained together

Comment: Is that only a /2 cable from/to the outlets? It seems like that whoever wired this did some really naughty things...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That is what I am thinking.  I am trying to wrap my head around what they did.  I do know there was a trail wire going from one switch to the other, I just don't know how it was configured.  There are only two wires to work with, one coming from the bottom of the diagram (floor) and the other one at the top of the diagram (ceiling).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, I need to know how many wires are in the cable from the bottom of the diagram...

Comment: There's no red wires anywhere??!!!??

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ahh, there are just the three.  (Black, white, uncovered or ground wire)

Comment: @Tyson nope, all the wires are black, white or uncovered

Comment: Can you give us a photo or diagram of the innards of the first of the ex-half-switched receptacles?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Just uploaded photo's, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @TheMiddleMan -- can we have a photo looking into the back of the box? It's a real mess in there...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sure can, the back of which box?  The outlet or the switches?

Comment: @TheMiddleMan -- the outlet

Comment: If they followed the law when building the place, every wire junction will be behind an accessible cover.

Comment: One thing you could do is simply remove the one switch from the circuit entirely, then you'd be left with one switch that worked both the lights *and* the split receptacles. Just remove the switch on the right and connect the black wires together.

Comment: If you want to restore constant power to your split receptacles, you can cut your red wires and pig tail them to one of the black wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to wire what you have described (grounds not shown):

[image]

You have 3-wire cable wired to your split receptacles, which means there *should* be 3-wire cable running to your switch in order to complete the circuit.

If there is only a 2-wire cable wired to your switch, then the power for your lights must be coming from somewhere else, and your switches should be wired like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that's the case for him -- I suspect something naughty is going on with the switched outlets, instead...

Comment: @ShemSeger The odd thing with the configuration I had was the traveler wire.  I know there was in fact a traveler wire connecting the two switches.  I am wondering if they used the traveler wire to transfer power to the other switch because there is only one line coming in with power.

Comment: Unless they're 3-way switches, there won't be a traveler wire.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan I wouldn't suggest putting it back the way it was, I'd suggest putting it back together *correctly*. The easiest thing to do would probably be to find the end of the run for your lights, and wire that to the nearest power source, then wire your light switch as an end-of-run switch.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can't think of any other way to make it work without using one of the grounds as a conductor wire, which would be *very* naughty.

Comment: @ShemSeger I can definitely try that tonight and see what happens.  Thank you so much for your diagram :D

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer because it is how the current switches should be wired.  I am going to call an electrician and have them fix it the proper way.  This is DIY requires a professional

Comment: @ShemSeger -- I indeed suspect that one of the grounds is being pressed into service as a neutral (I've seen this before on this site).  I just want to see a better inside-the-box photo before I make a final call on this